# Document.body.removeChild() only removes modal when in debugging mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding, event-handling, keyboard-events

I have attached a **keydown** listener in the constructor of my class like

```
constructor(props: DropDownProps) {
    this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(this.wrapper);
    ..
    this.confirm = this.confirm.bind(this);
    this.handleEnterKey = this.handleEnterKey.bind(this);
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleEnterKey);
}
```

The attached function, *handleEnterKey()* checks for the entered keycode and if it is the return key, it calls *confirm()*.

**handleEnterKey**:

```
private handleEnterKey(e: any) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        this.confirm(e);
    }
}
```

**confirm**:

```
private confirm(e: any) {
    this.onConfirmIn();
    document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleEnterKey);
    document.body.removeChild(this.wrapper);
    ConfirmationDialog.isConfirmationDialogOpened = false;
}
```

Now what is happening is that the modal doesn't vanish and enter needs to be pressed again. It seems the modal doesn't vanish until either:

1. Enter is pressed the second time
2. Breakpoint exists (no matter where)
3. The Modal is clicked upon, and then the enter is pressed

What could be the reason the modal doesn't simply detach itself on the first attempt?

Comment: Weird, but it works! Can you explain a bit as to why keydown didnt?

Comment: keydown also gives the keycode. handleKey events works every time I press Enter.

Comment: `keydown` events represent key being pressed and `keyup` - released. The right solution to get the keycode value is using the keyup method.

Comment: "keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed"
from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown.